# Get associated NSDocument for window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

How do I properly retrieve the NSDocument associated with the document window? I need the NSDocument as data source for displaying data in the window.

Do I have to iterate over all open documents and check if my instance is equal to the document's `-windowForSheet` or is there a more suitable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the window's [window controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller).  It might have a [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1534220-document) property which is set

```
MyDocument* doc = [[theWindow windowController] document];
```